# python category encoders on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I need to test several category encoders to different columns containing same values. All the values appear in the columns but not at the same row. For example, I could have:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({
'col0':["a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "d"], 
'col1':["c", "d", "b", "d", "c", "c"],
'col2':["b", "a", "c", "b", "a", "a"],
})

  col0 col1 col2
0    a    c    b
1    b    d    a
2    a    b    c
3    c    d    b
4    b    c    a
5    d    c    a
```

I could not have in the first row `"a", "c", "c"`

To encode columns I'm using the Python library [category encoders](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/index.html). The problem is that I need to fit the encoder with one column and then apply encoding on multiple columns.
For example given a `df` like this:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({
'col0':["a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "d"], 
'col1':["c", "d", "b", "d", "c", "c"]})

  col0 col1
0    a    c
1    b    d
2    a    b
3    c    d
4    b    c
5    d    c
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
  col0 col1  a  b  c  d
0    a    c  1  0  1  0
1    b    d  0  1  0  1
2    a    b  1  1  0  0
3    c    d  0  0  1  1
4    b    c  0  1  1  0
5    d    c  0  0  1  1
```

But using `category encoders` library I have to `fit` a column(s) and apply the `transform` to that same column(s).
Using `category encoders` on a column this happens:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({
'col0':["a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"], 
'col1':["c", "d", "c", "d", "c", "c"],
})
encoder = ce.OneHotEncoder(cols=None, use_cat_names=True) # encoding example to visualize better the problem
encoder.fit(dft['col0'])

encoder.transform(dft['col0'])
```

Output:

```
   col0_a  col0_b  col0_c  col0_d
0       1       0       0       0
1       0       1       0       0
2       1       0       0       0
3       0       0       1       0
4       0       1       0       0
5       0       0       0       1
```

Then apply transformation to the other column:

```
encoder.transform(dft['col1'])
```

Output:

```
KeyError: 'col0'
```

If the fit is done on both column (since col0 and col1 contain same unique values) the output is:

```
encoder.fit(dft[['col0','col1']])
encoder.transform(dft[['col0','col1']])

       col0_a  col0_b  col0_c  col0_d  col1_c  col1_d  col1_b
0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0
1       0       1       0       0       0       1       0
2       1       0       0       0       0       0       1
3       0       0       1       0       0       1       0
4       0       1       0       0       1       0       0
5       0       0       0       1       1       0       0
```

The example above is just a method to encode my columns, my goal is trying different methods, there are other libraries to do this encoding without applying transform method only to the fitted columns (without writing every category encoding method from scratch)?

Answer (score 1):

You can **[`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)** the dataframe to reshape then use **[`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)** to create a dataframe of **indicator** variables for the stacked frame, finally take **[`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)** on `level=0`:

```
enc = dft.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
out = dft.join(enc)
```

---

```
>>> out

  col0 col1  a  b  c  d
0    a    c  1  0  1  0
1    b    d  0  1  0  1
2    a    b  1  1  0  0
3    c    d  0  0  1  1
4    b    c  0  1  1  0
5    d    c  0  0  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually would prefer encoding every single column with a separate encoder, and I believe this behavior, you've described, is intentional. You could have columns `car color` and `phone color` being both `red` resulting in a same feature `red=True` indifferent to whether it was car or phone. But if you really want to achieve this, you could do a simple post-processing like this:

```
categories = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
columns = ['col0_a',  'col0_b',  'col0_c',  'col0_d',  'col1_c',  'col1_d',  'col1_b']

for category in categories:
    sum_columns = []
    for col in columns:
        if col.endswith(f'_{category}'):
            sum_columns.append(col)
        df[category] = df[sum_columns].sum(axis=1).astype(bool).astype(int)

df = df.drop(columns, axis=1)
```